# Subvariety as intersection of algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is well-known that the intersection of two algebraic varieties might not be a variety. Here the variety stands for the irreducible algebraic set. The counterexample is abundant. But what about the converse of this problem? Formally speaking:

> Given $X$ an algebraic variety in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and $Y$ an irreducible closed subset in it, prove that $Y = X \cap Y'$, where $Y'$ is another algebraic variety in $\mathbb{A}^n$.

I meet such a problem in my exercise, so I believe it should be true. But I have no idea how to prove it. Could anyone elaborate it for me?

Comment: You can take $Y' = Y$.

Comment: @ronno Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the description for remedy.